# How do I access the value passed into __init__.py by .run()

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My relevant file structure looks like this.

```
 Project
 -launcher.py
 -lib
 --bot
 ---__init__.py
```

launcher.py runs __init__.py in lib.bot like this:

```
#launcher.py
from lib.bot import bot

VERSION = "0.0.4"

bot.run(VERSION)
```

Here is where the issue is. I am trying to access the value of VERSION inside of __init__.py. I have tried using sys.argv but when I do that like this:

```
import sys
VERSION = sys.argv
print(VERSION)
```

it simply prints `['launcher.py']`.

I have tried lots of other ways to access this value but, try as I might: I am unable.
Any thoughts?

Comment: There's a nice tutorial about how to write and/or use modules and packages on the official website. You can find it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

```py
# __init__.py
VERSION = '0.0.4'
```

```py
# launcher.py
from lib.bot import VERSION    # access VERSION like this
print(VERSION)
```